# Why does FileNameSetter not activate inside ActionMenu?

Tags: gui-construction

Why doesn't this code work?

```
ActionMenu["select an option", {"choose a file" :> 
   FileNameSetter[Dynamic[x]]}]
```

Is there a way to get FileNameSetter to work inside ActionMenu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

two things to consider: `FileNameSetter` is used to generate a button which then subsequently gets pressed to open a window. When a window opens for you to select a file it is best to use the queued evaluation channel rather than preemptive.

Try this instead:

```
ActionMenu["select an option", {"choose a file" :> 
   (x=SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"])}, Method -> "Queued"]
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me a cleaner way to accomplish what I was after.  Much obliged.